# What does lambda in return lambda: object_list mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

What does `lambda` in

```
return lambda: object_list
```

mean or do? Can I remove it?

Object_list is here a list of objects requested from a remote server.

Comment: it returns an anonymous function that when called returns object_list ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambda is just a fancy way of defining a function on one line.

The code is logically equivalent to this:

```
def anon():
    return object_list

return anon
```

You may not simply remove the `lambda` here.  That will change the meaning of the code completely, returning the `object_list` directly as opposed to a returning a callable object.

Comment: of coarse he *can* delete it ... perhaps he shouldnt however.. :P +1